# Just downloaded Minecraft no bin folder or minecraft.jar

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've just downloaded Minecraft and I wanted to install Minecraft Forge, but it said I needed to go to bin folder than to minecraft.jar.  I don't have minecraft.jar, only having  versions, magic, launcher, launcher.pack.izma and launcher_profiles.json

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no Minecraft Forge for 1.7.4 yet and the folder as well as file structure changed drastically since 1.6.4 which the latest version was for.

Answer (score 2):

The new Minecraft launcher and all versions that it supports exclusively (1.6 and up) have no bin folder/minecraft.jar. Also, it seems that Minecraft Forge has not yet been released for Minecraft 1.7.4.

When it does come out, you can either install mods the recommended new way using the new launcher, or you can [directly edit the jar files](http://timtechsoftware.com/?page_id=1117).